# Optimise a Spring Boot backend for high CPU/memory workloads

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, resources, etl

I am running a Spring Boot application that acts as a backend for a frontend Javascript application. The frontend is served to the client as a static resource and the backend serves API requests coming from it. The application is initially designed to run on-premise but should be built in a way that allows easy porting to a cloud-native solution.

I expect the backend to do some heavy lifting ETL work which will be heavy on the memory and CPU side. At the same time, it won't need to scale to serve many concurrent requests - it only really needs to serve requests that kick-off and manage the jobs, which will be invoked by a single user who's interfacing with it.

What are some parameters that I could tweak to fine-tune for this type of deployment?

Current thinking:

- Reduce `server.tomcat.max-threads` to a single digit to minimize the footprint of the request thread pool as I am not expected to handle more than one-two concurrently
- Do the same for the database connection pool
- Fine-tune `Xms` and `Xmx` when launching the JAR

I would appreciate any other insights about how to make sure that the Java application takes up as big a footprint on the system as it can as well as Spring Boot specific parameters that I could tweak. Thank you.

Comment: This question is not focused enough and likely to attract opinionated answers. I therefore think, it is off-topic for SO. This is a Q/A platform, not a discussion forum or a mailing list.

Comment: Once your app is running, you can try tweaking the garbage collection settings and see how it affects your performance. Here is a helpful blog post about gc tuning:
https://blog.gceasy.io/2020/06/02/simple-effective-g1-gc-tuning-tips/

Comment: I agree with @kriegaex this is a very broad question. What seems to be the problem (having long-running business logic, webserver/servlet container, DB conn pool, JVM)? Why do you think it needs to be fine-tuned? And what did you try (profiling, metrics collection, load testing, etc.) to narrow down the possible bottlenecks if there are any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have long running background tasks, I would offload to work to a [threadpool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and set the maximum number of threads to the number of CPU's in your system. Also set a maximum capacity on the queue of the executor so you don't overload it with too much pending work.

Offloading to a different thread will make sure that the threads of the container remain available and you don't end up with a completely unresponsive system.

Your suggestions for the maximum heap size and connection pool are valid.

Comment: nice approach, another way I think would be useful was to enqueue the workload to a messaging system like RabbitMQ, this way you  could upscale consumers horizontally to perform acording to your needs

Answer (score 1):

Generally the optization techniques would be simialr to any Java based application and since yours is a ETL kind of processing where throughput is more important than individual request latencies.

If the task is typical ETL - then generally the transformation is more CPU intensive as compared to extract and load which are IO intensive. So my first suggestion would be to profile your application to understand  typical CPU/Mem usage pattern. If it spends more time in IO then you can live with much more number of processing threads than the CPU cores so you can tune that. Also remember that if the memory pressure is too much then a considerable CPU is spent by garbage collector as well so max memory settings would be important as well. You can enable GC logging in your application as use tool like [this](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) to analyze GC patterns easily. You can experiment with ParallelGC algorithms which is more suited for high throughput
at the cost of slightly high pause time. Typically if you have large data to interact with in extract and load phase you generally tend to use streaming/buffering techniques to reduce your memory footprint. An example is using cursors while dealing with large resultsets while interacting with database. Similarly if the load phase involves interaction with large files you can use parallel processing. then But all these would need experimentation to validate.

On a side note there is another project in Spring Ecosystem - Spring Batch which uses lots of such optimization techniques suited for batch processing for ETL types of job. You can read about some of techniques [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html).